# Error when exporting app that used Proguard

Tags: android, proguard

I try to use Proguard in my app. I wrote this code in proguard.cfg file:

```
    -optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class   Mp4ParserWrapper.** { *; }
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

When export app get **can't find referenced class** error .I search on the internet and add this line **-keep public class   Mp4ParserWrapper.** { *; }** to proguard file but don't solve problem .
Console :

```
[2015-10-16 17:29:09 - nabege] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2015-10-16 17:29:09 - nabege] Warning: com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.mjpeg.OneJpegPerIframe: can't find referenced class javax.imageio.ImageIO
[2015-10-16 17:29:09 - nabege] Warning: com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.mjpeg.OneJpegPerIframe: can't find referenced class javax.imageio.ImageIO
[2015-10-16 17:29:09 - nabege] Warning: com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.mjpeg.OneJpegPerIframe: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-10-16 17:29:09 - nabege] Warning: com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.mjpeg.OneJpegPerIframe: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-10-16 17:29:09 - nabege] Warning: com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.mjpeg.OneJpegPerIframe: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-10-16 17:29:09 - nabege] Warning: com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.mjpeg.OneJpegPerIframe: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-10-16 17:29:09 - nabege]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2015-10-16 17:29:09 - nabege] Warning: there were 6 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2015-10-16 17:29:09 - nabege]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2015-10-16 17:29:09 - nabege] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2015-10-16 17:29:09 - nabege]  at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2015-10-16 17:29:09 - nabege]  at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2015-10-16 17:29:09 - nabege]  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2015-10-16 17:29:09 - nabege]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
[2015-10-16 17:29:09 - nabege] Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xms256m -Xmx512m
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add `-dontwarn com.googlecode.mp4parser.**`

Comment: I would add that you probably don't need to have the "keep public class Mp4ParserWrapper" line in your Proguard config with aiwiguna's answer implemented above.

Comment: did you delete  -keep public class Mp4ParserWrapper. { *; } like Bradford2000 said?

Comment: OK. I add this line into proguard file and solved :-dontwarn com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.mjpeg.OneJpegPerIframe

Comment: sorry i forgot its need two asterix :(
-dontwarn com.googlecode.mp4parser.**

Comment: Sorry but I'm have the exact same issue, but your advices aren't working... :(

Comment: see all your warning message, "Warning: com.googlecode.mp4parser.xxxxxxxxxxx", and add it to proguard as -dontwarn