# Er: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I am getting below error while generating a signed Apk.

```
Warning:com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.mjpeg.OneJpegPerIframe: can't find referenced class javax.imageio.ImageIO
Warning:com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.mjpeg.OneJpegPerIframe: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:there were 6 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
```

Can anyone suggest what changes needs to do with progaurd.

I have also set below code in progaurd-rules.pro.

```
-dontwarn java.awt.image.BufferedImage
-dontwarn javax.imageio.ImageIO
```

But the same issue raised.

Comment: You should follow this link and I it should work : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33172549/error-when-exporting-app-that-used-proguard